# Cannot get DOM view html page with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

When im get the page

```
 public void getHtml() throws IOException {
    String html = Jsoup.connect("http://vp.by/").get().html();
    System.out.println(html);
}
```

Jsoup returns me

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

How can i get the full page in the DOM view?
(sites such as google.com, facebook.com getting normally)

Comment: Jsoup.connect() returns Document. This class should give you everything you need. Document.toString() should give you the HTML in string.

Comment: @Raviu I did as you said 
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://vp.by/").get();
System.out.println(doc.toString());
But it still returns an empty DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is vp.by is doing something to detect odd connections it deems not valid browser requests. If for instance you do curl -v -X GET http://vp.by you will just get a 200 OK response with no content. Adding the User-Agent header we are better able to mimic a valid browser based request.

Try the following:

```
public void getHtml() throws IOException {
    String html = Jsoup
            .connect("http://vp.by/")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36")
            .get().html();
    System.out.println(html);
}
```